# How to find $2^{2^{2^{2^0}}}$?

Tags: arithmetic

What is the result of $2^{2^{2^{2^0}}}$?

Comment: From top calculate the powers and reduce the "height".  It is not at all difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

If exponentiation is indicated by stacked symbols, the usual rule is to work from the top down, because exponent is [right-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) in mathematics.

thus:

$a^{b^c}$     =  $a^{(b^c)}$

which typically is not equal to $(a^b)^c$

Basically, exponentiation implies brackets around the exponent.

Thus, this boils down to $2^{2^{2{^{2^0}}}}$. So then:

$2^0 = 1$, so that makes $2^{2^{2{^1}}}$

$2^1 = 2$, so now we’re at $2^{2^2}$

$2^2 = 4$, so we get $2^4$

$2^4 = 16$, and that's our answer.

Seems simple enough.

Answer (score 3):

Power towers are grouped down from the top, so take the top $2^0=1$, then proceed downward.

Answer (score 2):

$2^{2^{2^{2^0}}}=2^{2^{2^1}}=2^{2^2}=2^4=16$

Answer (score 1):

Given problems like this, we always have to start from the topmost exponent and base which here is 0 and 2 respectively. So we have $ 2^0=1 $ and then proceeding likewise we have $ 2^1=2 $ and $ 2^2=4$ and finally, $ 2^4=16 $ as the answer.